# How can I see the value assigned to a variable in Ethereum solidity language?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity

I would like to know the value assigned to a variable of Ethereum solidity language.

In JavaScript, even if I don't know what type of variable it is, I can use `console.log` to output the value of the variable.
i.g)

```
    ....
    .........
        var l = Math.ceil(8 * n.length / (Math.log(t.length) / Math.log(2))),
        console.log(I);
            c = Array(l);
        console.log(c); // This can be very useful when I want to know what value is outputting, such as using console.table
    ..........
    ....
```

As you may know, these are often useful methods when analyze and debug code.
How should I implement this method like `console.log` in the "solidity"?
i.g)

```
    ...
    ......
    wonder = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(now, msg.sender, Rnd_entropy_2))) % Ana; 
    // There are three variables in this line: "Ana, Rnd_entropy_2, wonder". I want to know what value assigned to each variable has and what they are output. 
    // In JavaScript, Can easily be found console.log (Ana, Rnd_entropy_2, wonder). What should I do?
    ....
    ........
```

Isn't there an easier way to get there? I'd be happy to hear what your thoughts are on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have functionality in solidity like console.log()
If you are using Remix then you can check the value of variables there.
Run transaction in deploy and run transaction tab and check variable values afer running corresponding function

Answer (score 1):

At this moment (August of 2022) you can use `console.log()` with help of this import

```
import "hardhat/console.sol";
```

[Ref](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/whats-the-solidity-statement-to-print-data-to-the-console)